# Upload document in Document Library using memorystream programmatically

Tags: document-library, openxml

I opened existing word document using openxml. Now i need to upload the same document into Document library with memory stream. If i did so my content controls inside the word document gets disappeared. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

if SharePoint 2010 or 2013 you can use the [File.SaveBinaryDirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538285%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method available on the client-side object model. Sample code:

```
            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(docLibUri))
            {
                clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

                // Getting stream from SQL Server
                GetStreamFromSQLServer(pFileStreamId, ref reader, ref stream, ref fileName);

                if (stream == null)
                    throw new Exception("Stream cannot be null");

                if (fileName == null)
                    throw new Exception("Filename cannot be null");


                // Full file path
                String filePath = String.Format("{0}/{1}", docLibRelativePath, fileName);

                // Uploading stream to Document Library
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, filePath, stream, true);

            }
```

Comment: File gets uploaded, but changes in content control is not reflected. I searched and found we need to update customxmlpart while updating content control value. But i don't know how to update single value in customxmlpart.